# Implement Interface with custom method and JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on an API Rest, registration  for students, using Domain Driven Design. So my problem is: I'm trying to add a custom method with the JpaRepository. My Project hierarchy is:

```
com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.model.StudentModel;  
com.wizardry.witchcraft.infraestructure.repository.CustomRepositoryImpl;  
com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.repository.IStudentRepository;  
com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.repository.ICustomRepository;
com.wizardry.witchcraft.api.controller.TesteController2;
com.wizardry.witchcraft.api.controller.StudentController;
```

So first I've created the method Implementation

```
 import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.model.StudentModel;
    import com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.repository.ICustomRepository;

        @Repository
        public class CustomRepositoryImpl implements ICustomRepository {
        
        @PersistenceContext
            private EntityManager manager;
            
            @Override
            public List<StudentModel> findCustom (String name){
                //METHOD
    
            }
        
        }
```

And the Interface:

```
import com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.model.StudentModel;

public interface ICustomRepository {

    List<StudentModel> findCustom(String name);

}
```

And to test it out I created a new Controller to don't mess with my working one, `TesteController2`, and it worked fine. So  my next step was extended the `ICustomRepository` in the `IStudentRepository`, made the changes in `TesteController2` and then Spring won't find my `findCustom` method anymore, It tries to create the method as a JPA keyword and return and error. This is my repository interface:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.model.StudentModel;

@Repository
public interface IStudentRepository extends ICustomRepository, JpaRepository<StudentModel, Long> {
    
      List<StudentModel> queryByName(String name, @Param ("id") Long school);
      
      List<StudentModel> queryFirstByNameContaining(String name);
      
      List<StudentModel> queryTop2ByNameContaining(String name);
      
      int countByWizardingSchoolModelId(Long school);
     

}
```

And the TesteController2:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.model.StudentModel;
import com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.repository.IStudentRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class TesteController2 {

    @Autowired
    private IStudentRepository iStudentRepository;

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    @GetMapping
    public List<StudentModel> findCustom2(String name) {
        return iStudentRepository.findCustom(name);
    }
    
}
```

PS: I have a Service Layer com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.service.RegisterStudentService however
the method in question does not go through it (yet!) because I'm testing, I tried to pass by the service and see what happen but give the same ERROR.

> ERROR: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'registerStudentService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registerStudentService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'iStudentRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IStudentRepository' defined in com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.repository.IStudentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.wizardry.witchcraft.domain.repository.ICustomRepository.findCustom(java.lang.String)! No property findCustom found for type StudentModel!

I'm really lost here.

Comment: That must be because of the naming convention that JPA follows. Try renaming `findCustom` with JPA standard. Ex. Consider you StudentModel has `name` field, then rename method to `findByName`. It should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename your class CustomRepositoryImpl to IStudentRepositoryImpl and it should work.

```
      @Repository
    public class IStudentRepositoryImpl implements ICustomRepository {
    
    @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager manager;
        
        @Override
        public List<StudentModel> findCustom (String name){
            //METHOD

        }
    
    }
```

Below is the documentation from Spring

> Configuration If you use namespace configuration, the repository
> infrastructure tries to autodetect custom implementations by scanning
> for classes below the package we found a repository in. These classes
> need to follow the naming convention of appending the namespace
> element's attribute repository-impl-postfix to the found repository
> interface name. This postfix defaults to Impl.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations